# Where can I buy IOTA in USD?

Tags: economics, sales, exchanges

Coinbase is where a lot of people safely buy their ETH and BTC, but it doesn't appear Coinbase currently sells IOTA. What are some places that I could buy IOTA from?

(Note I'm not asking for the *best* place, just somewhere I can get my foot in the door.)

Comment: This is not a stackexchange relevant question. Stackexchange is for technical questions.

Comment: @cyclux I think this a fair question as IOTA is not just a technology but also a currency. So questions about buying and selling it are natural.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a technical question and additionally any answer may be obsolete very soon

Comment: Noting that these questions are on-topic for other crytocurrency SE boards, I've asked for clarification, here: https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/are-questions-about-buying-and-selling-iota-on-topic (Happy for it to be off-topic though.)

Comment: SE doesn't have boards and it's not a forum;)

Comment: *sites :-) I've developed the bad habit of labelling them "boards"... (And treating Meta as a chat room... ish)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately direct USD to IOTA isn't available yet, you will need to buy another crypto-currency first, transfer it to an exchange that trades IOTA and trade it there. The best/cheapest way to buy IOTA differs from moment to moment and can be found on https://iotaprices.com/ - This includes instructions on how to do so. Buying Ethereum is currently recommended over Bitcoin since it has cheaper fees and tranfers faster.

Answer (score 4):

### How to Purchase IOTA in the US

---

Overview on how to purchase IOTA in November of 2017 in the US. For the sake of simplicity I am going to use [Ethereum](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/ethereum-transactionfees.html) (ETH) as an example. [Bitcoin](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html) (BTC) could also be used here (w/ higher fees).

1. Create a [Coinbase Account](https://www.coinbase.com/signup) (recommend 2-factor authentication)
2. Create a [GDAX Account](https://www.gdax.com/) (owned by Coinbase, same market)
3. Link a [new bank account](https://www.coinbase.com/settings/linked-accounts) (Increase your [Buy and Sell limits](https://www.coinbase.com/verifications) ASAP if necessary)
4. Transfer funds from [linked GDAX account](https://www.gdax.com/accounts) (which now has access to your Coinbase bank account, this will not require any fees! It will take 3-5 business days to transfer.)
5. [Buy ETH](https://www.gdax.com/trade) using LIMIT/STOP (this allows you to do market orders without fees)
6. Transfer your cryptocurrency to another exchange where IOTA is traded, such as [Binance](https://www.binance.com/) where you can buy IOTA for ETH (lower fees than BTC). Visit [GDAX accounts](https://www.gdax.com/accounts) to withdraw your cryptocurrency from it to a [Binance equivalent](https://www.binance.com/userCenter/depositWithdraw.html). This transfer will accrue fees, as it is from one ETH address to another.
7. [Trade ETH for IOTA](https://www.binance.com/trade.html?symbol=IOTA_ETH), it will also accrue ETH fees for each transfer that occurs.

Congratulations you’ve purchased IOTA!

---

### What now?

[Generate a seed](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-to-generate-a-seed-safely) and store your IOTA seed in a safe place such as in paper form or protected by KeePass. If you lose your seed, you lose your IOTA. I do not recommend storing your IOTA on any exchange for long term.

### Learn More

[Official IOTA Site](https://iota.org/)

[What is IOTA?](https://iotasupport.com/whatisiota.shtml)

[Conversion Tools](https://laurencetennant.com/iota-tools/)

[Slack Channel](https://iotatangle.slack.com/)

[Github Organization](https://github.com/iotaledger)

For free IOTA to play with visit [r/IOTAFaucet](https://www.reddit.com/r/IOTAFaucet)

Google Authenticator for 2 factor authentication [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en) or [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-authenticator/id388497605?mt=8)

[IOTA Wallet](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/releases)

---

**Note**

This is not the only way to buy IOTA in the US. Hopefully going thoroughly through a real world example helps you understand what you need to do. Especially if you decide to deviate from the above example.

Answer (score 3):

I live in US and bought IOTA by doing the following:

1) Bought ETH from CoinBase

2) Transfer my ETH to Binance

3) Bought IOTA with ETH through Binance

Answer (score 2):

1) Buy BTC or LTC from [CoinBase](https://www.coinbase.com)

2) Transfer BTC or LTC to [CoinSpot](https://www.coinspot.com.au?affiliate=G3WX4)

3) Buy IOTA with BTC through CoinSpot

4) Send IOTA from CoinSpot to your IOTA wallet

(CoinSpot is an Australian exchange you might be more comfortable using as a US citizen than an Asian based exchange)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there are no exchanges that exchange USD for IOTA. Your best (also fastest and cheapest) method would be to exchange USD for LTC on Coinbase, then send the LTC to an exchange that trades LTC, BTC, and IOTA such as Bittrex or Binance. Once your LTC is moved from Coinbase to the other exchange, sell the LTC for BTC, then use the BTC to purchase IOTA. Unfortunately this is currently the fastest and least expensive method for exchanging USD for IOTA.

Comment: Coinbase is very user friendly but also has quite high exchange rates and trading fees. You are better of at other exchanges, price-wise.

Comment: Alternatively, you can deposit to Coinbase, then login to GDAX and buy there, which is a Coinbase owned exchange with lower fees.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should buy some bitcoin or ether on any exchange, and then You can buy IOTA tokens on Bitfinex.com or www.binance.com. Is what i did actually I've bought some ether on coinhouse.com and then use it to buy IOTA on bitfinex