# My Iota got transferred without my consent

Tags: transaction

This morning a transfer was completed with a [transaction](https://thetangle.org/transaction/BLZYVPMC9RWSEPNCQIZBCUZYRTCOGPOGZNAXBWJLJSPR9MTNHFEWDTVBWWJWSEXEANDZXOFNMHA9A9999) and the funds ended up at this [address](https://thetangle.org/address/KRDTGTERZCIXCCAE9ERSLFD9UWIYSKKXALVUTDVAOGZLNOOTKVHRWWTNRPFPTWSQMRCYR9HGMCSATQUPY).

Needless to say I haven't made this transfer and that I am puzzled by this. I had my seed done by a recommended Iota source (can't remember which).

Any ways I can recover this—or get help by the Iota community?

Comment: You need to provide more information, which wallet are you generally using, did you transfer other IOTA around the same time et cetera...

Comment: I have the 2.5.4 version - just came back from holiday and didn't log in for a while.

Comment: Is it possible that you generated your seed on a site which was not [this one](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdqTgEdyKVQAVnfT5iV4ULzTbkV4hhkDkMqGBuot8egfA)?

Answer (score 5):

Your seed was probably compromised when you generated it on a malicious website. 
There are various ways to [generate a seed safely](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-to-generate-a-seed-safely).

If the transaction moving funds to an address that you don't own is confirmed: there is no "normal" way to get your funds back (and otherwise it would be a terrible flaw in IOTA design).

The only way to get your funds back is that the iota community agree to restore a snapshot anterior to the ofending transaction. This kind of event occurs once in the past when the whole community decide to authorize the transfer of all funds at risk due to adress re-use to a secure adress owned by the iota foundation (that's the the reason of the "reclaim" process).